# How do you visualize ridge, roof and step edges?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I am reading about Canny algorithm in the book *Academic Press - Handbook Medical Imaging Processing Analysis* where it is written that the algorithm was originally developed for antiasymmetric edges $(f(x)=−f(−x)$, where the true edge point is at $(x=0)$ such as ridge, roof and step edges. 
I am also discussing about the options for this algorithm [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31821/32299).

How can you visualize ridge, roof and step edges?